How can I fetch a random video ID from this database?
I have uploaded my app in a play store as a beta version, but when I fetch a video URL from the app the app it is only fetching a first URL video and always it is fetching that video at first. Can we make it to fetch randomly from firebase?
Note: I can't edit a app file for now
here is diagram for database


I just need to choose  a random video from it.
It needs to be suffle everytime automatically from firebase.

Can you provide the code you've written so far? :)
